# Number to Binary conversion in a Legacy application

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

One of the functions of an access card legacy application converts a number to binary and stores it in MS SQL DB field type `binary(9)`. This field contains Wiegand 26-bit format card numbers, and the biggest number that can be stored is 65535.

*We do not have the legacy application source code*.

When we convert the number to binary using `select cast(number as binary(9))` and when the application converts it, there is a difference between the results.

**Example:** 38741

Legacy App:

> 0x000000000055970000

`select cast(38741 as binary(9))`:

> 0x000000000000009755

I can see some kind of pattern in the output difference. Here are some more samples:

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Number</th>
  <th>LegacyAppOutput</th>
  <th>SqlCastValue</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>38741</td>
  <td>0x000000000055970000</td>
  <td>0x000000000000009755</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>27250</td>
  <td>0x0000000000726A0000</td>
  <td>0x000000000000006A72</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>27249</td>
  <td>0x0000000000716A0000</td>
  <td>0x000000000000006A71</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>27248</td>
  <td>0x0000000000706A0000</td>
  <td>0x000000000000006A70</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Is there any function (in either SQL of C#) which performs number-to-binary like the legacy application does?

Comment: Without looking into it much, it looks like a difference between little- and big-endianness (where sql server is big-endian and your legacy output is little-endian) - you may or may not be able to find some solution to your problem by looking for something that reverses this.

Comment: @ ZLK, Thank you for the endianness tip. . Now I can continue . :)

Comment: For those who wants to know about Big and Little Endian Byte Order:https://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-big-and-little-endian-byte-order/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the endianness of the numbers. Here is an example of how to do it:
http://www.csharp-examples.net/reverse-bytes/.
Unfortunately there is no method to do this.

Comment: Thank you for the endianness tip. ((UInt16)((val & 0xFFU) << 8 | (val & 0xFF00U) >> 8)); gave me the ouput similar to lagacy system. Now I can continue . :)

Answer (score 0):

**Reason behind this issue**

Difference between little- and big-endianness *(where sql server is big-endian and legacy application output is little-endian)*. Thanks to ZLK & michauzo for the tip.

**Solution**

You should do both conversion (number to binary and binary to number) in same way. ie. both should be done in either sql or in application development. Problem starts when you do one conversion in sql and other one in application development.

**So how I get the desired number.**

> byte[] intAsBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(cardNo); //generate little-endian.

Then insert 5 bytes to the array // specif requirement to match with the legacy output.

Then directly save to the SQL DB.

For those who wants to know about Big and Little Endian Byte Order: https://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-big-and-little-endian-byte-order/